# triple nested loop prints excessive characters

Tags: java, loops, nested

I am working on a program and in I try to print a board that is 10x10.  If my object coordinates match the iteration of the i and j loop integers then the object's char should print if not the loop should print '- '.  However on my third nested loop since 15 of the objects coordinates dont match the program prints excessive amounts of '- '.  How can I simply print the char when one of the coordinates match while keeping the board form.
The board should look like this

```
. . . . . . . . a .
. . e . . . b . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . .c . . . . . .
. . . . . . . d . .
. . g . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . h . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

and my code for the print method is

```
public static void printGrid(bumpercar bcar[], int NUMCARS)
{
    //nested loop
    for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
    System.out.printf("\n");
        for(int k = 0; k<16; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l<NUMCARS; l++)
             {
            if((bcar[l].getX() == k) && bcar[l].getY() == j)
            System.out.printf("%s", bcar[l].getCarSymbol());
            else
            System.out.printf("- ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in something like

..........K.....................................................................
.........................................
................................................................................
................................................
.................................................N..............................
.........................................
....................I...........................................................
.........................................
..........................F.....................E............................L..
...........................
........................H...M.P...................O........J....................
.............
.............C...G..............................................................
..............B............
..................................A........................................D....
..................................
................................................................................
................................................

any ideas how to format the if statements to achive this? thanks

Comment: I suggest that you download NetBeans, Eclipse, or a similar IDE and learn to use its built-in debugger. This is a powerful, and essential tool, for any programmer. You can step through your code one line at a time and check that it behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Change your innermost loop to:

```
        boolean found = false;
        for(int l = 0; l<NUMCARS; l++)
        {
          if((bcar[l].getX() == k) && bcar[l].getY() == j) {
            System.out.printf("%s", bcar[l].getCarSymbol());
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.printf("- ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing a character each time you find a car that doesn't need to be at a given cell.

Fixed code:

```
public static void printGrid(bumpercar bcar[], int NUMCARS)
{
    //nested loop
    for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        System.out.printf("\n");
        for(int k = 0; k<16; k++)
        {
            int l;
            for(l = 0; l<NUMCARS; l++)
            {
                if((bcar[l].getX() == k) && bcar[l].getY() == j) break;
            }
            if (l == NUMCARS) {
                // no car at this location
                System.out.printf("- ");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s", bcar[l].getCarSymbol());
            }
        }
    }
}
```